# ESP8266 library / function for IR remote control

Tags: programming, esp8266, ir, remote-control

I am using [IRremoteESP8266](https://github.com/markszabo/IRremoteESP8266) for reverse engineering Hitachi AX-M76E mini stereos IR controller. I want to read the signal that the remote sends and send the same hexas to the stereos with IR led.

*Please let me know if this is wrong site* but I am trying to find out one thing on that IRremote library that is missing on it: code and protocol for Hitachi. There are even example code for Sony and other well known marks but Hitachi is missing.

Receiving IR is universal:

```
void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    // print() & println() can't handle printing long longs. (uint64_t)
    // So we have to print the top and bottom halves separately.
    if (results.value >> 32)
      Serial.print((uint32_t) (results.value >> 32), HEX);
    Serial.println((uint32_t) (results.value & 0xFFFFFFFF), HEX);
    irrecv.resume();  // Receive the next value
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

With this loop I am able to fetch IR hex codes from remote control but with the next code I still cannot wake any action on stereos:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println("NEC");
  irsend.sendNEC(0x00FFE01FUL, 32);// put the received hexa here
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Sony");
  irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12, 2);
  delay(2000);
}
```

What you see every manufacturer uses their own protocol. I tested NEC because its protocol seemed to match what I received, still I did not succeed.

What may be the correct code, if I rewrite the sendNEC function so that I get the Hitachi one?

Comment: Now when I look this again, it seems that the problem is that the result code is 64 bit and NECsender parametr is 32. I have to verify that. Code that I received was longer than that I used in example.

Comment: HI, did you get solution of this problem. I'm using the same library to get the Panasonic AC remote IR code. It returns the different-different code for Same On/Off button with encoding protocal as UNKNOWN. I also get the Time line data, which is raw data.

Can I get the raw data from IR code?